# terraform custom script on Azure VM scale set failing with managed identity

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to download a blob from a private container in a VM scale set custom script, using a managedIdentity. This is my terraform code:

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux#property-values
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "res-extension" {
  depends_on = [
        azurerm_storage_blob.example
    ]

  name                         = "nn-extension"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = module.vmss.vmss.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                         = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version         = "2.1"

  protected_settings = jsonencode({
      "fileUris" = ["${azurerm_storage_blob.example.url}"],
      "commandToExecute" = "sh createfile.sh ; ls -al",
      "managedIdentity" : { "objectId": module.vmss.vmss.identity.0.principal_id }
    }
  )
}
```

However, it fails with the message:

```
"Error message: \"Enable failed: processing file downloads failed: failed to download file[0]: failed to download response and write to file: /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/1/createfile: failed to create http request: Unable to get managed identity with object id 2c8.....8. Please make sure that the user assigned managed identity is added to the VM"
```

I checked in the portal, I have an active Managed Identity on the VM scale set, with matching principal ID.

When I change the setting to use 'clientId' instead of 'objectId' it throws a similar error.

So is it possible to use a Managed identity to download blobs? Or do I have to assign user assigned identities to individual VM instances in the scale set or something??

Anyone any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was already in here:
[Azure VM Scaleset custom script extension not working - possibly failing to get VM identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927429/azure-vm-scaleset-custom-script-extension-not-working-possibly-failing-to-get?rq=2)

When using managed identity pass an empty block:

```
"managedIdentity" : { }
```

Didn't read the docs well enough...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#property-managedidentity